# How to get unique value of a pandas series keeping the order of occurance same

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this -

```
    TEST_NUM  SITE_NUM  RESULT TEST_FLG              TEST_TXT UNITS LO_LIMIT HI_LIMIT
0       150         0 -0.4373        P  Continuity_PPMU XSCI     V       -1     -0.3
1       150         1 -0.4383        P  Continuity_PPMU XSCI     V       -1     -0.3
2       150         2 -0.4357        P  Continuity_PPMU XSCI     V       -1     -0.3
3       150         3 -0.4370        P  Continuity_PPMU XSCI     V       -1     -0.3
4       151         0 -0.4646        P  Continuity_PPMU XSCO     V       -1     -0.3
```

As you can see TEST_TXT has repeated values in it. There are around 53 unique values in TEST_TXT.

Q> I want to get all the unique values in `TEST_TXT` series keeping the order same, something like `['Continuity_PPMU XSCI','Continuity_PPMU XSCO',..etc]`.

Currently, when I am using `np.unique()` it is changing the order, though it gives unique value.

I can iterate the dataframe, keep a map to check if it a value has appeared already or not, if not, I can append to a list. This way I can have the unique values also in the same order but I was looking for a more elegant way, more python way(or pandas/numpy).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply switching from [`numpy.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to [`pandas.Series.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) will do the trick.  NumPy gets unique values using sorting while Pandas uses a hash table and specifically says in the documentation that the results are in the order they originally appeared.

So like this:

```
df.TEST_TXT.unique()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use drop_duplicates directly to your Series:

```
df['TEST_TXT'].drop_duplicates()
```

Will give you what you want, keeping the order

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to have solved the problem too. Accepting John's answer simply due to time. Thankful to you as well. +1.

Comment: Only option which worked currently. I tried categorical did not work.